# when i try to upload a file i got the following error(Request for permission)

Tags: asp.net

This is the error:
   Error uploading file: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Cultural=netural,
PublickeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' filed

Where i'm going wrong?

thanks saj

Answer (score 0):

Do you have permission to write the file to the upload location? You may have to giver write permissions to the asp.net user.

**EDIT** - A quick search of the net throws up this:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/436a125b-675a-4897-abce-624c92d7fb1c